# How To setImageBitmap from Url (https) (java)

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I used this function to convert url to bitmap :

```
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

then i used setImageBitmap, but my app didn't launch, can u tell me some way to store image into sqlite ?

Comment: I believe you have your app function call in mainThread. It must be doing in the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of good usage for get image also i dont know what are your use case.

> > Internet permission need!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**First Solution**

Since you are using java . Im gonna use RxJava For that.

```
public static Observable<Bitmap> fetchImage(String rawUrl) {
    return Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Bitmap>) emitter -> {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(rawUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            emitter.onNext(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));
            emitter.onComplete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            emitter.onError(e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
    });
}
```

You're also need to implement [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)

And Here How you call it

```
 Observable<Bitmap> requestImage = fetchImage("https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2022/09/jonatan-pie-3l3RwQdHRHg-unsplash.jpg");
    requestImage.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap) {
                  // set bitmap to ImageView here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

**Secondly**

I may recommend [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
        Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2022/09/jonatan-pie-3l3RwQdHRHg-unsplash.jpg")
            .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView));
```

For Glide it set image direct or you can manage to set it in call back

**Thirdly is Asynctask(deprecated)**
Note : There are a more that this 3